# How to Strip Time from Date Time and store in PSQL using Python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, psql

I have a situation where i want to strip time from my date time object and store in database (PSQL precisely)

How do you do it ?

```
>>> print(datetime.now())
2016-06-28 16:22:30.918715
```

What i want is

```
2016-06-28
```

and store it into PSQL database

What is the best way to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer cause it took me around an hour to find the answer and hope it helps to someone.
The best solution as for of now i have found is

```
dt = datetime.today()
2016-06-28 16:22:30.918715

dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
2016-06-28
```

Basically psql stores data in type string so the code dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') will strip off your time and return you a string data type and you can store it.